# help with Jsonp and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have a web service served in jsonp, but since I'm new to this I have difficulties retrieving the data. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
   $.getJSON("http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=central,victoria&return=name&jsonp=myData",
       function myData(result){
           $('#status').append(result.name.text);
        }
   );

});
```

the div #status returns empty.

could you help?

Thanks in advance

Mauro

Update: now it works! Bout it does't when I'm trying to loop though the data:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=central,victoria&return=name&jsonp=?",
         function (result){
              $.each(result.items, function(item){
                 $('#status').append(item.response.lines[0].name);
        });
     }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that the jsonp object is being return correctly? A helpful tool for this is called Fiddler.

Comment: @Aaron yes think it does. Try it yourself go to: http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=central,victoria&return=name&jsonp=myData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

I think your code should look something like this

```
$.getJSON("http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=central,victoria&return=name&jsonp=?", function (result){
    $('#status').append(result.name.text);
});
```

The trick is the `json=?` part of the URL. I think jQuery creates a function on the fly to parse de JSONp data and feeds the result to your callback function.

Excuse my English :)

**Update:** to access the data you must iterate over `result.response.lines` inside the callback function

```
$.each(result.response.lines, function() {
    $('#status').append(this.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks now it works! How do I loop trough the result? See my code in the updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the output of the URL:

```
myData({"response":{"lines":[{"name":"Central"},{"name":"Victoria"}]}});
```

You can reformat the object to make it clearer:

```
{
    "response": {
        "lines": [
            {"name":"Central"},
            {"name":"Victoria"}
        ]
    }
}
```

I see no property called `text`. You probably mean:

```
$('#status').append(result.response.lines[0].name);
```

**Update:** this solution doesn't fully solve the problem. As suggested in the accepted answer, you need to instruct jQuery to generate a random function name (you cannot provide your own, not at least with getJSON).